# c++ Запись в bin файл

Tags: c++, файлы, c++14

Начал писать свой оптимизатор-транслятор кода for fun. Я новичок в c++ и ЯВУ.
Ввожу число с консоли. Пример 1048575.
Этот код записывает в файл 00 0F FF FF:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int exe[100000];
    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open("s.bin", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    int n = 0;
    while (n < 10000) {
        cin >> n;
        int n1 = n & 255;
        int n2 = (n>>8) & 255;
        int n3 = (n>>16) & 255;
        int n4 = (n>>24) & 255;
        ofile << static_cast<char>(n4);
        ofile << static_cast<char>(n3);
        ofile << static_cast<char>(n2);
        ofile << static_cast<char>(n1);
    }
    ofile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Почитал что лучше работать с binary так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int n;
int main()
{
    fstream f;
    f.open("s.bin", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    while (n < 10000) {
        cin >> n;
        f.write((char*)&n, sizeof(int));
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но этот код пишет число не в том порядке, получается FF FF 0F 00.
1.Как исправить второй код?
2.Или лучше пользоваться своим велосипедом в первом? - Так как порядок байт я планировал контролировать в алгоритме при генерации.
3.Почему советуют второй код для работы с binary файлами? Проявятся ли какие-то "неудобства" при разрастании кода если оставить первый код?

Comment: htonl ntohl поможет привести к одному виду

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Если уж С++, то надо с файлами работать как с потоками (ifstream, ofstream, fstream), а не старыми сишными функциями. Но даже и старыми сишными функциями проще писать в файл сразу int, как во втором примере. Зачем Вам самому разбивать целое на байты? Это дело транслятора и системы ввода-вывода.

Comment: Ага, второй пример int сразу пишет, но как я понял в little endian, я хотел в big.

Comment: Я не могу понять как в первом примере писать сразу int, во втором не знаю как байты развернуть.

Comment: С порядком байтов разобрался. Как в первом коде int записывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне непонятно, почему вам непонятно :), что вы **прочтете ровно то, что запишете**.

Если вы записываете число с переставленными байтами - понятно, что вы и прочтете число с переставленными байтами, и вам действительно потребуется "костыль" - либо ваш, либо написанный более эффективно, скажем, в виде ассемблерной вставки.

Вопрос - зачем вам вообще писать байты не в том порядке? Почему вы решили выбрать именно big endian, работая на машине с little endian? Так ли это принципиально *"for fun"* (c)?

Второе - непонятно, откуда такие "советы", использовать подход C. Как правило, выбирается что-то одно - либо подход C, либо подход C++. Говорить, что лучше, а что хуже - развести тут holywar, так что скажу только, что они абсолютно совместимы по результатам и в конечном счете работают через API операционной системы :)

Comment: Мне так удобнее. Стоп, то что я считаю неудобным, это default - litle endian?

Comment: Ну, зависит от того, где вы работаете :) - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Я понял! -  Мне показалось что сначала байты в обратном порядке пишутся, а потом еще инвертируются - ночью уже сидел, сам выдумал проблему! "зачем вам вообще писать байты не в том порядке?" - Для генерации опкодов процессора. Я начитался процессорных опкодов с hex редактора, отчего возникло желание перевернуть байты:). Теперь я понял ошибку.

Comment: Как в первом коде сразу int записывать? P.S. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Примерно так: `ofile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n),sizeof(int));`. Ну или покороче :), но не в духе С++ - `ofile.write((char*)&n,sizeof(int));`

Comment: Работает. Можете объяснить как работает(C++ style)? Почему там опять этот char?

Comment: Просто это аналог `fwrite`. Функция `write` должна получить указатель на `char`, указывающий на данные в памяти, и количество записываемых байт - вот мы и приводм адрес переменной к указателю на `char`. А вот - описание этой функции: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write Читать - аналогично: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

Comment: Тяжело пока понять. Сразу не отходя: Как читать?

Comment: Да точно так же: `file.read((char*)&n,sizeof(n));`

Comment: Разобрался в тот же день, все работает, решил отписать. Спасибо.